# Is a dependent variable with both negative and positive values in a linear regression an issue?

Tags: regression, linear-model

The dependent variable is continuous and has negative and positive values as it is a percent change. ***My question is, can one use such a variable as a dependent variable in a linear regression model?*** If not, what type of transformations are feasible or how could this potential problem be addressed?

I have considered transforming my continuous variable to a categorical variable ("positive" for values above zero, "negative" for values below zero, and "average" for values equal to zero) and perform a multinomial model instead of a linear, with the "average" as the reference category.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: “dependent variable is ... a percent change” That might not be the best way to set up your model. There’s no problem with having both positive and negative values for a dependent variable, but it is often best to model the actual outcome observations, perhaps using the pre-treatment values as predictors. It’s possible that the residual errors in percent-change values won’t meet the standard assumptions of linear regression. Please say more about the details of your study, to ensure that linear regression is the right approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First to confirm that there is no objection in principle to an outcome variable in regression being variously positive, zero and negative. The question is as always whether the functional form matches the main pattern in the data.

I don't see a strong case for jumping to a reduction to categorical form.

But percent change can be a problematic metric for various reasons, mostly obvious but still fundamental.

1. If the initial amount is 0, any change from that is not defined.
2. If the initial amount is very small, very large values are possible by division.
3. Often there is a sharp lower limit of -100% which may bite in the data.
4. Following from #2, in contrast, there is no obvious upper limit.

In practice, none of these may bite in many datasets.

Although it doesn't seem often done, various suggestions have been made to use

change / (mean of previous + current)

(or some variation on it) as a more symmetric measure.

I would always want to see the data and learn more about the context to give more specific advice.

Answer (score 0):

It is always helpful if you include an example. For example, what is the scale of your outcome variable? Generally, if your dependent variable can take on values between $\infty$ and -$\infty$, then linear regression is appropriate. However, if the scale is extremely large, i.e. going from -1000 to 1000 and you don't have many data points, I would consider transforming to categorical values, even though this should be avoided. Reducing your outcome to categories removes a lot of the signal as it is easier to map your independent variables to a continuous variables rather than arbitrarily chosen categories. Hope this helps.